# python redefining `attrs.field` to accept default argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-attrs

How do you redefine the attrs.field function (and type hint it) to accept a default argument? This is my current code.

```py
from attrs import define, field


def fixed_attr(default, **kwargs):
    return field(default=default, repr=False, init=False, eq=False, **kwargs)

@define
class A:
    number: int = fixed_attr(10)
```

Should I use `Literal[10]` instead of `int`? Do I need to type hint the output of `fixed_attr`? Why do my type hinter (pylance/pyright) still show `number` as an argument?